# Pymysql Python 2.7 with unicode utf8 thai language error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I have using pymysql.connect with python 2.7 to connect MySQL V.5.6.36 Server chaset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)and result shown error with

> "u'\u0e1b\u0e15\u0e17.\u0e40\u0e01\u0e35\u0e22\u0e23\u0e15\u0e34\u0e4c\u0e1b\u0e34\u0e22\u0e09\u0e31\u0e15\u0e23'"

but the correct should be show in thai Language so i also add for charset="utf8" but still show same problem

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
connection = pymysql.connect(host="www.xxxxxx.xxxx",
                             user="xxxxxx",
                             passwd="xxxxx",
                             db="test",
                             charset="utf8",
                             use_unicode=True
                            )
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql1 = ("SELECT "
        "ID,"
        "expired_date,"
        "name  FROM site")

cursor.execute(sql1)
date_check = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Check how is the table created: `SHOW CREATE TABLE site;`. It should have `DEFAULT CHARSET utf8` at the end, if it has `latin1` (default) then that's the cause of error.

Comment: I have checked and found at "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" .Thanks